# how to make a dynamic radio-group button in ionic ngfor and pass to typescript what the user selected

Tags: typescript, ionic2, radio-group

API end point

http://questionaires.itresourcesgroup.com.au/public/networking

**HTML**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submitNetworkingForm()">
     <div  *ngFor="let item of networkingdata;let i = index;" >
                           <ion-list  *ngFor="let inner of item;let b = index;" radio-group [(ngModel)]="answers" name="answers" >
                                   <ion-label>{{b}} . {{inner[i][b].question}}</ion-label>
                                      <ion-item   *ngFor="let innermost of inner[i];let c = index;">
                                        <ion-label> {{innermost.answer}}</ion-label>
                                        <ion-radio  [value]="innermost.answer"></ion-radio>
                                      </ion-item>

                            </ion-list>
                    </div>

                <button ion-button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

I want to make the model dynamic. Something like this in php:

```
echo '<input type="radio" name="salutation_description[]" value="'.$row1[0].'"/>'
```

then pass to typescript.

Comment: I want to get the value of each selected radiogroup in typescript please help

Comment: can I remove this post ? I solved it on my own already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed 
[(ngModel)]="answers" name="answers"  in this block of code and it works like a charm

```
  <ion-list  *ngFor="let inner of item;let b = index;" radio-group [(ngModel)]="answers" name="answers" >
```